# Why does subtraction in $\mathbb{Q}$ have no neutral element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In each case, decide whether the operation $*$ on $A$ is associative, commutative and has a neutral element.

c) $A = \mathbb{Q}$ and $x * y = x - y$

In the answer in the book, it says that it doesn't have a neutral element. I did it this way:

$x * y = x \implies x - y = x \implies -y = 0 \therefore 0$ is the neutral element.

Comment: Check the definition of "neutral element": I'm guessing that it requires the neutral element to work when substituted into *either* variable, not just $y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a set $S$ and operation $\ast$ to have a neutral element $e$, we need $e$ to satisfy
$$
s \ast e = e \ast s = s \text{ for every } s \in S
$$
Is $0$ a neutral element of subtraction on the rationals? Note that
$$
2 - 0 = 2 \text{ but } 0-2 = -2 \ne 2
$$
which poses a problem.

At best, you can argue it is a right-sided neutral element (since $x-0=x$ for each $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ - but typically when calling something "a neutral element" we mean a two-sided one).